# Forcing ASP.NET WebForms to render __doPostback() scripts

Tags: asp.net, webforms, postback, rendering

One of our ASP.NET WebForms 3.5 pages just suddenly decided not to render the `__doPostBack()` javascript method, along with the supporting `<hidden>` fields, anymore.

Everything else seems OK on the page - the only thing I changed was that I removed a postback handler on a `SelectList` control, and changed `AutoPostback` from `True` to `False` on the same control. There are still several other (unchanged) elements on the page that have postback handlers.

I'm also using jQuery validation on the page, but it was working like a charm before, and I haven't changed anything in the javascripts. And yes, I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480946/asp-net-dopostback-not-rendered-sometime), but that solution does not  apply to me - we're not using any caching at all at the moment.

**UPDATE:**
It seems that ASP.NET is deciding my client scripts aren't needed, since no controls are [depending on postback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hc29e2a.aspx). However, I have a button control for submitting, which has an event handler on the server side, and that event handler is never called - I suspect this is because the button is allowed to be just a regular `<input type="submit">` and submitting the form in standard HTTP ways, instead of with the ASP.NET `__doPostBack` script.

This is my control (visible is set to `True` in code-behind):

```
<asp:Button ID="SaveNewButton" runat="server" CssClass="inputbutton"
    Visible="false" OnClick="SaveNewButton_Click" />
```

And this is the handler method in code-behind:

```
Protected Sub SaveNewButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object,
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveNewButton.Click
```

How do I force ASP.NET to render the client scripts for postbacks, so my event handler is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, as tdammers noted, that ASP.NET only renders the `__doPostback()` javascript when it thinks it's needed, and in this case it didn't think so. The solution was given to me in [a thread at forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/p/1584561/4006822.aspx#4006822) and was as simple as this:

Set [UseSubmitBehavior="False"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior(v=VS.80).aspx) on the button that should submit with `__doPostBack()` and not using the browser's default submit behavior.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, ASP.NET only renders the __doPostback() javascript when it thinks it is needed, that is, if there are controls on the page that need to trigger a postback while the HTML controls they render do not natively do so. A button can trigger a postback through a regular non-scripted submit, so your dropdown might have been the only control needing the scripted postback. When you changed its autopostback property to false, you probably removed the need for __doPostback, so ASP.NET doesn't render it anymore.

Comment: This seems plausible. Is there any way to force ASP.NET to render the scripts?

Comment: The answer by @Stan below includes a method to force the scripts to be rendered.

Answer (score 2):

In case you find this via Google, the issue is that the __doPostBack is included only when needed.  If you don't have any controls that cause the script to be included by ASP.NET automatically, you can call

```
        page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(New Web.UI.PostBackOptions(Me.page))
```

And ASP.NET will include the postback scripts.  Simple.

You can do this in a `PreRender` event handler.

REF http://forums.asp.net/t/1584561.aspx?Forcing+ASP+NET+to+render+__doPostBack+scripts

Answer (score 0):

Does your <form> tag still have the runat="server" attribute?

Comment: Yes, it does, as do all the other server controls on the page.