# Safari, ASP.NET 4, and LinkButton

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, .net-4.0, safari, asplinkbutton

I have an ASP.NET Web Application using .NET Framework 4 and it is working fine on all browser when I test it locally using my Visual Studio Pro 2010, but when we deploy it to our server (IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 R2), the `LinkButton`s of my Web Application is not working correctly on *Safari Browser* on all platforms.

What was happening was when the `LinkButton` has a function that uses `Response.Redirect`, it somewhat clears the session or doesn't save it. I can check this since when I redirect to another page, I save the values inputted to a session first before redirecting, and validate it to the redirected page and if there's no session, bring it back to the previous page.

I have already implemented [this fix to add a `.browser` file to my webapp](http://www.marauderzstuff.com/PermaLink,guid,ebdcf5dd-ecdf-4260-b55a-04708b252e08.aspx) but it doesn't fix my problem. I also tried [this answer from SO to add a `Page_PreInit` and a configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12827863/1115937) but to no avail.

My IIS Configuration has enabled for both Session and Cookies, and I honestly do not see why it will only affect *Safari Browser* if it is a server configuration error.

I've been working on this bug for a whole day and I can't still fix this. Please help, thanks in advance.

**Update:** I forgot to mention that my website is inside an `iframe`, after researching further I have found [this question that says that Safari doesn't allow *Third-Party Cookie* by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930671/safari-3rd-party-cookie-iframe-trick-no-longer-working). Now I can't use the said fix since my application is in ASP.NET not in PHP.