# MVC.NET 2 with iPad

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ipad

I'm facing a problem when browsing my website with a tablet (asp.net MVC 2 and browser is mobile safari or the android one).
When submitting a form, my model isn't binded and I get some errors.
This only happens with a tablet (I tried iPad and ACER iconia tab A200).

Here is my model :

```
public class ChoixVehiculeImmatriculationModel : Model
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ImmatriculationRequise", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Erreurs))]
    public string Immatriculation { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my view :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ChoixVehiculeImmatriculationModel>" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <div id="immatriculation">
            <% Html.BeginForm("ChoixImmatriculation", "ChoixVehicule", FormMethod.Post );  %>

            <table id="tabImmatriculation">    
                <tr><td><%= Libelles.SaisissezNumeroImmatriculation %> :</td></tr>
                <tr><td><%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Immatriculation, new { maxlength = 20, autocomplete = "off" })%></td></tr>
                <tr><td>
                    <div id="btnValider">
                        <div class="btnValidText" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();"><%= Libelles.Valider %></div>
                    </div>
                </td></tr>
            </table>

            <%Html.EndForm(); %>
        </div>

    </asp:Content>
```

Here is the controller :

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult ChoixImmatriculation(ChoixVehiculeImmatriculationModel model)
    {
        if ( ModelState.IsValid )
        {
            using ( IVehiculeUIService vehiculeService = GlobalContainer.Resolve<IVehiculeUIService>() )
            {
                List<VehiculeModel> vehicules = vehiculeService.GetListeVehiculesParImmatriculation(model.Immatriculation);

                return GestionRetourSelonResultats(vehicules);
            }
        }

        return View("ChoixVehiculeImmat", model);
    }
```

The `ModelState.IsValid` is false and it says that the field `Immatriculation` is `null`.
But the textbox has been filled !

It happens randomly at start. I have to do it like 5 times for it to work sometimes..
On my laptop, it never happens, everything is working nice..

Can anyone help me please ?
Maybe a difference between browsers and mobile browsers ?

Comment: Have you tried an actual submit button rather than that div with javascript? Since you're creating a form right there, the submit button will act on that. Also, you aren't nesting forms, are you (eg. one in the layout/masterpage file)

Comment: Can you check that the textbox does NOT have the same id: `immatriculation` as the surrounding div? Just a way code is generated in the HtmlHelpers...

Comment: I just tried with a submit button, same issue.

Comment: No nesting forms, I just checked. thx.

Comment: @Tallmaris : they have the same id.. I just changed the id of the div but I still have the problem.

Comment: Maybe it's related to the problem I ran into in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804493/safari-on-ipad-occasionally-doesnt-recognize-asp-net-postback-links)?  I wasn't working with ASP.NET MVC, but the underlying problem (ASP.NET not recognizing Safari as being javascript-capable) is causing your issue?

Comment: @Derek : On the iPad, the issue is occurring both on safari and on an app named Kiosk Pro. They are both recognized as the following : `Version/5.1 Mobile/9B176 Safari/7534.48.3 `or `Version/6.0 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25` so it's seems to be OK on that side, thanks

Comment: It seems that the app I'm using is Safari-based.. I installed Chrome on the iPad and there is no more problem. Weird, mobile Safari can't handle POST ? Javascript problem or something ?

Comment: Safari and Chrome are both WebKit.... They should essentially render the page the same.

Answer (score 0):

Given it happens randomly and doesn't happen in Chrome (which uses exactly the same rendering engine on the iPad as Safari) it is obviously a race condition.

Is the HTML displayed in the browser [HTML valid](http://validator.w3.org)? Perhaps there is a problem there?