# Why use ClientTarget = "uplevel" in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on asp.net web form application, in  register page, autopostback does not work properly in safari browser, 
I found solution but i want to understand

```
string ua = Request.UserAgent;
if (ua != null
    && (ua.IndexOf("iPhone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
    || ua.IndexOf("iPad", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
    || ua.IndexOf("iPod", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    && ua.IndexOf("Safari", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
{
    this.ClientTarget = "uplevel"; // what does this mean?
}
```

Please explain me what is meaning of uplevel.

Reference link :http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2011/05/29/Gotcha-iPad-versus-ASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clienttarget(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ClientTarget property gets or sets a value that allows you to override automatic detection of browser capabilities and to specify how a page is rendered for particular browser clients.
>
> - uplevel, which specifies browser capabilities equivalent to Internet Explorer 6.0.

So in your case: With `this.ClientTarget = "uplevel"` you are making sure your application runs properly in your Safari browser.

Comment: but my condition is totally different from actual code :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804493/safari-on-ipad-occasionally-doesnt-recognize-asp-net-postback-links